# Does the induced Electric field develop instantly or lags by $\frac rc$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, faster-than-light, induction

Consider a loop of radius $r_0=3 \times 10^8$ cm. A thin bar magnet is passed through its center. This implies that the magnetic flux through the loop will change. Now according to Faraday's law a *non conservative* electric field must develop inside the wire of that loop.

**Question:**

> Let the magnet be cross though the centre at time $t_0$. Then would the electric field develop in the wire at $t_0$ or at $t_0+\dfrac {r_0}c$?

**Commentary**

According to the Faraday's Law of Electromagnetic induction the electric field $E(t)$ developed inside the wire is given by the following mathematical relationship,

$$\oint \mathbf{E}(t_0) \cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell} = - \dfrac{d \Phi(t)}{dt}|_{t=t_0}$$

According to this, the electric field developed at time $t_0$, $E(t_0)$ has a magnitude which directly depends upon the rate of change of magnetic flux at time $t_0$. This implies that the information of the motion of the magnet can be transmitted at any distance instantly. I might be wrong. If I am not wrong then this fact can be used to create paradox by applying special theory of relativity.

The second case can be that the electric field doesn't develop instantly and lages its cause by $\dfrac {r_0}{c}$. If this is the case then the current in the loop will develop after a time interval of $\dfrac {r_0}{c}$, then this current will create its own magnetic field which will cause a change in magnetric flux, and a net change in magnetic flux will be observed after $\dfrac {r_0}{c}$, this net change in the flux will cause its effect on $E$ at time $\dfrac {2r_0}{c}$. But we know that in the analysis of a pure conductor, V-I characteristic is solved by differential equations which gives a solution free of $c$. So either this second case is incorrect or the V-I characteristic of the pure inductor.

Thank You.

Comment: Your first option certainly isn't true, the E field cannot develop instaneously. The solutions of Maxwell's equations are retarded as in your second option. I cannot see why you think Lenz's law causes any paradox. Any B field set up in the wire opposes the original changing magnetic flux.

Comment: @RobJeffries There will be a paradox if my first option is correct. If my second option is correct then the Faraday's law must be modified and the analysis of self induction and mutual induction should also be modified. I will also have to make the steady state analysis. Can you provide an analysis of V-I characteristic of a pure inductor, considering the r/c delay. All the differential equations will have to be changed too.

Comment: That sounds like a difficult problem, but that is what must happen. Faraday's law, as you have written it, cannot apply. But of course Maxwell's equations do.

Comment: @RobJeffries  Your first comment is not satisfactory.  Faraday's Law does not appear to account for retardation. Also Note that we don't specify the spatial configuration of the surface whose boundary is the loop.   The surface can be distorted to any shape, including shapes in which parts of the surface are very far from the loop. (I typed this *while* you were submitting your second comment.)

Comment: If the magnet is moving uniformly in an inertial frame of reference, there is an associated non-conservative electric field (in that frame) in addition to the magnetic field of the magnet.  This is true *regardless*.  One merely transforms the purely magnetic field in the rest frame of the magnet using the relativistic electromagnetic field transformations.  If the magnet is *not* inertial then the 'information' of the change in the magnet's velocity propagates away at $c$.

Comment: @garyp what do you disagree with? The integral form *as written in the OP does not apply*. The differential form of Faraday's law of course does.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The magnet is initially at rest before $t_0$, then at $t_0$ it accelerates and after some time reaches at a particular velocity say $v_0$ and passes through the centre of the loop. I think you are right, the info of the motion at $t_0$ will reach the loop at $t_0 + r_0/c$. What I want is further references and texts that analyse the behaviour of inductor keeping these things in consideration.

Comment: @RobJeffries How is the differential form of Faraday's law correct? It also says that Electric field will be observed instantly with the change in B.

Comment: @RobJeffries First comment, "_Any B field set up in the wire opposes the original changing magnetic flux_" THere will be a current which would produce it's own B and this will cause a change in the magnetic flux, the changed change in flux will cause a different current which will further change the B, and this will be going until a steady state reaches.

Comment: @seuser32111, the differential form is *local*; it relates the curl of $\vec E$ at a point to the time rate of change of $\vec B$ *at the same point and time*.

Comment: @RobJeffries I don't disagree.  As I pointed out I was responding to your first post.  The question leaves me curious about the conditions for validity of the integral form.  Also, I've always believed that the differential forms and the integral forms were equivalent, at least if the whole set of four equations are considered as a whole.  So where did retardation go in the integral form?  Is there a "Faraday's Law" that takes into account retardation?

Comment: @garyp Let's ask! I honestly had not thought too much about it, but it seems clear that they cannot be straightforwardly applied.

Answer (score 2):

This should be considered a *provisional* answer.

First, let's make the setup concrete.

- There is a thin conducting circular loop in the $xy$ plane with
  radius $r_0$.
- There is an ideal magnetic dipole aligned with and located on the $z$
  axis and initially at rest at $z = z_0$.
- At time $t = t_0$, the dipole begins accelerating along the $z$ axis.

Now, let the elapsed time since $t = t_0$ be

$$\Delta t = t - t_0 $$

and the (static) magnetic field at time $t = t_0$

$$\vec B_0 = \vec B(t_0)$$

Then, according to special relativity, the changing magnetic field and associated electric field cannot reach the loop until an elapsed time of

$$\Delta t_l = \frac{\sqrt{r^2_0 + z^2_0}}{c}$$

For $\Delta t < \Delta t_l$, the magnetic field *outside* of a sphere of radius $c\Delta t$ and centered on $(0,0,z_0)$ is just $\vec B_\text{outside} = \vec B_0$ while *inside*, the magnetic field is $\vec B_\text{inside} = \Delta \vec B(t) + \vec B_0$.

This means that, while $\Delta t < \Delta t_l$, *no magnetic field lines of $\Delta \vec B$ thread the conducting loop.* $^1$

So, here's the provisional answer:  the *flux* of $\Delta \vec B$ through the surface bounded by the conducting loop is proportional to the number of lines of $\Delta \vec B$ *threading* the loop.

Thus, for the surface bounded by the conducting loop,

$$-\frac{d\Phi(t)}{dt} = 0\; ,t < (t_0 + \Delta t_l) $$

---

$^1$ To be clear, I mean that no field line of $\Delta B$ can *cut* the loop before $t = t_0 + \Delta t_l$

Comment: @Timaeus, I disagree with you.  For there to be a net flux of $\Delta \vec B$ through the surface bounded by the ring, at least one field line must have 'cut' the ring and that cannot be the case at $t = t_0 + \frac{z_0}{c}$.

Comment: @Timaeus, I edited the answer to clarify what I mean by "thread the loop".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An experimentalist's answer

It is experimentally established that the underlying framework of nature  is quantum mechanical. Changes in electric and magnetic fields create electromagnetic waves. Thus photons propagate the changes/information in your experiment, they are the quantum of energy in electromagnetism.

It is also experimentally established that special relativity holds. This means that the information of changes in magnetic and electric fields cannot be propagated  faster than the velocity of c that controls the behavior of photons.

There is no instantaneous propagation of energy as far as we have established by experiments and observations.

Comment: Please explain in detail. When I move the magnet it changes the magnitude of magnetic field at the centre of the loop. How many photons does this create? In which direction they move? How does a changing magnetic field(not E) create a photon, which has both B and E at 90 degree. AFAK a photon has sinusoidally varying E and B. But if I move the magnet at a constant speed then the B will change linearly. Also how can I make a V-I characteristic of an inductor having one loop, considering r/c delay? Which experiment does prove that only changing B produces a photon?

Comment: When you move  a magnet you are generating an electromagnetic pulse, photons. The number of photons might be estimated by the energy of the motion if the frequency were known, the frequency will depend on the dx/dt of the motion. changing electric / magnetic fields produce electromagnetic pulses, i.e. photons.

Comment: as for inductors and V-I it is the huge velocity of light that to all useful purposes makes the macroscopic formulation accurate. It is instantaneous within time scales in the lab.